# Modifing a preference via applescript changes file group

Tags: macos, command-line, permission, firewall

I recently request help about modifying firewall settings via command-line (see my previous [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186635/update-preferences-panel-after-using-default-write/186649)).
Everything is working, but I have noticed that whenever I use this command in an applescript, the file group changes from `wheel` to `staff`.

Before:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel
```

After running the script:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  staff
```

Repairing Disk Permissions fixed the issue but change it to `admin` instead of `wheel`.

After fixing permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin
```

However, I want to know:

1. Why is this happening, and
2. if it can raise security issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, it doesn't matter.

`ls -l` print out consists of status (10 character), number of links, owner, group, etc.

Of the first 10 characters describe file type(1), owner permission(3), group permission, and permission for others. In the case of

```
 -rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel
```

File type: `-` means regular file.

Owner Permission: `rw-` means user `root` can read and write.

Group Permission: `r--` means user(s) in group `wheel` can read only.

Others: `r--` means user(s) not in group `wheel` can also read only.

So you don't have to read the rest to know there is not security risk for what the group is.

So what are the users in `wheel`, `admin` and `staff`?

```
$dscacheutil -q group -a name wheel; dscacheutil -q group -a name staff; dscacheutil -q group -a name admin
```

You get:

```
name: wheel
password: *
gid: 0
users: root 

name: staff
password: *
gid: 20
users: root 

name: admin
password: *
gid: 80
users: root YourUserNameHere
```

`wheel` is a legacy thing from UNIX. OS X never bothered to change it. When you `sudo` the file, `sudo` automatically use group `staff`. If you don't want the group name to change on the file, do:

```
sudo -g wheel defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.alf globalstate -int 2
```

Comment: I knew how to read the file permissions, but I didn't know about the wheel/staff groups relation. Thanks for clarify this.